# How do I multiply the values from the same column based on the same index in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple columns and multiple distinct indexes so i am confused with the logical flow

```
   list1  list2  list3
A      2      3      4
A      1      5      7
B      2      3      8
B      6      1      2
C      4      2      2
C      2      4      5
```

my desired result would be :

```
   list1  list2  list3
A    2.0   15.0   28.0
B   12.0    3.0   16.0
C    8.0    8.0   10.0
```

Comment: I'm curious, what is the use case for this? In what context do you need to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`DataFrame.prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.prod.html) with `level=0`:

```
df1 = df.prod(level=0)
```

Alternative solution is use [`GroupBy.prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.prod.html) by index:

```
df1 = df.groupby(level=0).prod()
#alternative
df1 = df.groupby(df.index).prod()
```

---

```
print (df1)
   list1  list2  list3
A      2     15     28
B     12      3     16
C      8      8     10
```